# Display multiple row with data according to ID value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, microsoft-excel-365, range

I want to ask as well about this.

For example:

One ID has multiple rows with value (one row is equal to one dependent).

So ID:001
Has 4 rows (4 dependents)

`001 | Marie | 03/23 | Female`

`001 | Raffy | 11/20 | Male`

`001 | Luffy | 05/06 | Male`

`001 | Boney | 01/01 | Female`

How can I display it when I type his ID and all of these data should appear regardless of how many rows/dependents an ID has?

--

Done so far:
=Vlookup(E3,A2:D100,2,False)

--

I have done VLOOKUP but all I'm getting is the first row's value. I want all of the other values associated with A2's value (001) to be displayed.

Comment: you can use a filter ? or a pivot table with slicers, there would be many vba options to but you probably don't need something that complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the array formula, you may try Index+Small+If.

On my sample, I use `=IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:B$7,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=$G$2,ROW($2:$7)-1,4^8),ROW(A1))),"")`, then press Ctrl + Shift +Enter.

[image]

Then fill down to find the persons who match the ID. Then fill in to the right and find other information about this person.

Choose the cells of Date, set Date format.

[image]

Comment: Okay, nice. This is the answer I'm looking for. I also looked up to INDEX and AGGREGATE, and I think for me this is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `FILTER()` function was made for. Just use:

```
=FILTER(  A2:D100,  A2:A100=E3  )
```

and all is displayed for the given ID, no sorting of the data required.

Basically it says take this range (A2:D100) and look for any records in the first column (A2:A100) that match the ID value in cell E3 and return EVERY row that matches.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as well.